# AMS Linux Instance showing wrong output for `fdisk -l` command

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, awstats

Recently I made an AWS AMI from scratch. Now when I log into my instance it shows below output for `fdisk -l` command:

```
% sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/xvde1: 10.7 GB, 10737418240 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1305 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/xvde2: 160.1 GB, 160104972288 bytes <<<<<<<<<
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19464 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/xvde3: 939 MB, 939524096 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 114 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

Here is my `/etc/fstab` file entries which I specifically made for this instance at the time I was building the AMI from scratch.

```
/dev/xvde1 /      ext4 defaults       1 1 none 
/dev/pts   devpts      gid=5,mode=620 0 0 none 
/dev/shm   tmpfs       defaults       0 0 none 
/proc      proc        defaults       0 0 none 
/sys       sysfs       defaults       0 0
/dev/xvde2 swap   swap defaults       0 0
```

Now I'm confused why it's showing excessive 160 GB partition.

**NOTE:** This is a small instance store instance. I've restarted the instance twice.

Answer (score 0):

The 160GB volume is the instance storage for your VM.  It is ephemeral and will not survive the system being shutdown so do not use it for anything you actually want to keep.

As to why it is showing up in place of your swap volume, I'm guessing that you passed a conflicting "-b" value to "ec2-run-instances" when you launched it because your swap is xvde3.